# return value calculated from javascript FileReader onload event

Tags: javascript, callback, onload, filereader

I have this function:

```
function doStuff(range, file) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var hash = '';
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        var out = "stuff happens here";
        hash = asmCrypto.SHA256.hex(out);
        return hash;
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return hash;
}
```

Right now, the function completes before the onload event is finished, so doStuff always returns "".  I think a callback is what I need, but I'm new to javascript, and I can't wrap my mind around how to implement it in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

File reading using File Reader is asynchronous operation. Place your logic inside the `onload` function of file reader.

```
function doStuff(range, file) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        var out = "stuff happens here";
        hash = asmCrypto.SHA256.hex(out);
        /* Place your logic here */
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

You can even pass a callback function that will be executed once the file is read.

```
function doStuff(range, file, callback) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        var out = "stuff happens here";
        hash = asmCrypto.SHA256.hex(out);
        /* Assuming callback is function */
        callback(hash);
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: No idea. There seems to be nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Even same here. I don't know why ppl do down voting simply :(

Comment: It can also be noted that there is a [synchronous `FileReader` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync#readAsArrayBuffer()) available in Firefox only (and even then only in a web worker context).